# Native Azure Database for PostgresSQL vs PostgresSQL dock container in an Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Azure provides "native" database service for [`postgressql`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/postgresql/) as well as a few other popular database engines. Meanwhile, I could also create a VM and run a postgres docker container in it to provide database service to my application.

What would be the pros and cons for each approach?

- Performance?
- Pricing?
- Flexibility?

Thanks in advance. New to Azure and Cloud space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pricing :**

Azure Database for PostgreSQL costs you bit more than installing it on a VM. However you should go for a D instance in VM considering the fact that no SLA is given for other instance. In that case price becomes almost [`equal`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql/).

**Flexibility:**

As usual, like with SQL Paas, Certainly with **[`Azure database for PostgreSQL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-limits)** With PaaS support the migration easily and do not need to worry about the replication etc. This provides scaling
of frequent queries with intelligent query processing which is best for modernization at scale with low effort.

**Performance :**

It Depends on the CPU, RAM and HDD speeds/cache/usage and everything. If you give the VM low resources and high demand, it will of course, perform poorly.
The true answer would be that you can only know if you install a testbed and try it under real-world use.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. What if I need to install a custom extension to postgres such as [sequential-uuids | https://github.com/tvondra/sequential-uuids]. I can do that easily in a docker image. I am not sure if it is even possible to install custom extension in a Azure database for postgressql instance.

Comment: The extensions which you could install are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-extensions

Answer (score 1):

You should probably search definition of IaaS and PaaS. The proc and cons are obvious from the definition. IaaS gives you flexibility, but requires management effort (at the very least, it can also require licensing), whereas PaaS doesnt require you to manage\plan anything, but takes away the flexibility. you are locked to certain versions of a product, they often support a subset of features so on and so fourth.